# "Refresh" a lambda object

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I created my lambda like so:

```
int i = 0;
auto gen_lam = [=]() mutable -> int {return ++i;};
```

It effectively counts the number of times it has been called, because it stores the captured `i`.  Is there a way to "reconstruct" the object so it starts out with the initial value of `i`?

Something  along the lines of:

```
decltype(gen_lam) gen_lam2;
```

such that the following code outputs `1 1` instead of `1 2`

```
std::cout << gen_lam() << std::endl;

decltype(gen_lam) gen_lam2;

std::cout << gen_lam2() << std::endl;
```

Comment: For simplicity and sanity, I would create a plain old functor class for this.

Comment: I would like to store it in a `std::function` and would hate to impose yet another type on the caller/user of my class

Comment: @TeaOverflow: As long as the added overhead for type-erasure is acceptable...

Comment: You can't `decltype` a lambda because you can't name its type.

Comment: You can store a functor in `std::function`

Comment: @40two How can it be `auto`'d then

Comment: @40two: That's no objection. You can't name types from the anonymous namespace either.

Comment: @TeaOverflow you have a definition there that why it can be `auto`'ed

Comment: @40two: Ah, I get your mistake. You can't do `decltype([]{}) lambda = []{};` because the two lambda's have different type. The fact that you can't _name_ those types is irrelevant. You have the same two-type problem with `decltype(1) foo = "one";`.

Comment: @40two http://ideone.com/iVhEbe

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply done, wrap your lambda-creation in a lambda, which you can call whenever you need the inner lambda re-initialized:

```
auto wrap_lam = [](int i) {return [=]() mutable {return ++i;};}
auto gen_lam = wrap_lam(0);
auto gen_lam2 = wrap_lam(0);
```

Or just make a copy to preserve the state whenever you want:

```
auto gen_lam = [=]() mutable -> int {return ++i;};
const auto save = gen_lam;
```

If you only ever want a full reset, naturally save as a const object first.

Comment: You can even write `auto const prototype = [=]() mutable { return ++i; };` so you know the prototype itself isn't accidentally incremented.

Comment: Nice...I didn't even think of capturing the pass-by-value counter in the generator.

Comment: @MSalters: Just wanted to make the point that it can be saved at any time one wants, not only at creation. Though of course, if only a full reset is desired, yours is preferable due to making logic-errors syntax-errors, which the compiler will complain about.

Comment: Thanks, copiing seems to be the best solution for my case. @MSalters Very nice idea with `const`. Will try!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the initial values that were captured by the lambda can be part of its type, because that would mean each time that code runs (with possibly different values of `i`) a new type would have to be generated at runtime.

I also don't think that the initial state of captured mutable values is stored, because that would take up extra memory.

So in summary, if all you have is a lambda function object which was created in the way you describe, I don't think you have any way to recreate its original state.

However, if you control the code which generates that function object, you can pull it into a function and just call that function again. Or you can make a function object class manually, as @NeilKirk already suggested.

Comment: The initial value of the captured variable doesn't need to be stored, since the original `i` is captured by value and therefor not "touched"

Comment: True, but the original `i` might have long gone out of scope. In your question, it wasn't very clear WHY you wanted to refresh / reset the lambda object, so I tried to solve the problem literally and with minimal assumptions - given *only* the lambda object, try to reset it or make a "refreshed" copy.

Comment: In your code, there will be two versions of `i`: One is the local variable (that remains unchanged throughout), and one is the value copy in the lambda. But that copy will be modified every time you call the lambda, so you'd have to go back to the original `i` to get the starting value, you can't get it by looking *only* at the lambda object itself.

Comment: I see the way you meant it now. But in my mind I thought that reconstructing the lambda object would similar to instantiating a functor's class, thus "re-capturing" the `i` that was used in the first place. This is why I attempted `decltype(gen_lam)`as a (wishful) means to get the object's type

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want could be done by having a generator that captures different counters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    auto lambda_generator = [](int& val) {
        auto var = [=]() mutable -> int {return ++val;};
        return var;
    };

    auto counter1 = lambda_generator(i);

    std::cout << counter1() << std::endl;

    auto counter2 = lambda_generator(j);

    std::cout << counter2() << std::endl;

}
```

If "reset" means you want a different counter.

Comment: The shared state of the second example freaks me out. Deduplicator's solution where each lambda has its own state is much nicer.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I agree...i didn't even think of capturing the copied pass-by-value integer. I'll leave my crappy answer here for pedagogical purposes.

Comment: @MSalters I'll remove the second example entirely

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the inner variables copied inside a lambda, but the lambda itself can.

By establishing a protocol over the call you can send commands to the lambda to mutate its state. For example:

```
auto counter = [](int i0){
    int i = i0;
    return [i0, i](bool reset=false) mutable {
        if (reset) {
            i = i0;
            return -1;
        } else {
            return ++i;
        }
    };
};
```

Here I'm using an optional parameter that when passed `true` will reset the counter to the initial value.

```
int main() {
    auto c = counter(10);
    std::cout << c() << "\n"; // 11
    std::cout << c() << "\n"; // 12
    std::cout << c() << "\n"; // 13
    c(true); // send reset message
    std::cout << c() << "\n"; // 11
    std::cout << c() << "\n"; // 12
    std::cout << c() << "\n"; // 13
}
```